# Rails image_tag doesn't show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following image tag in my view:

```
<%= image_tag "http://cdn2.sponsorpay.com/app_icons/26600/big_mobile_icon.png" %>
```

When I go to the url directly the image is visible, but embedded into my site, it doesn't show.

Any ideas why this happens?

Edit:
Must have to do with the link. As

```
<img src="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20131004141939/clashofclans/de/images/6/62/Barbar.png">
```

works, while:

```
<img src="http://cdn2.sponsorpay.com/app_icons/26600/big_mobile_icon.png">
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried putting it in a raw `<img>`? Rails `image_tag` is designed for use with app assets.

Comment: Still doesn't work with this link. However, a different image link works. So, it must be the link. But the link works, when you enter it directly in the browser.
Works:

    <img src="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20131004141939/clashofclans/de/images/6/62/Barbar.png">

Doesn't work:
    <img src="http://cdn2.sponsorpay.com/app_icons/26600/big_mobile_icon.png">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried just adding an `<img>` tag with that link to a page using Chrome's console and received an `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` message. It seems that the service hosting the image has disallowed other domains from requesting it.